# Can we set the Blueprint "populate" property of an individual model attribute in Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

Sails.js allows to set `populate: boolean` throughout the app. I wish to apply this property to an individual attribute, like so:

Globally:

```
populate: true
```

models/outlet.js:

```
pincodes: {..., populate: false}
```

Is this possible or will I have to write a custom `find` action in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to write your controller. The only other method of control would be to turn populate off globally and then you can specify what you want populated via the api on each request.

```
api.com/stuff?populate=associatedStuff
```

Assuming you have a complete api already, then your solution of doing a one off controller is probably best.